# Разрешения/Permissions, которых нет в Manifest

Tags: android

Не пойму, что за магия:

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<!-- используется API-интерфейсом для загрузки листов карты с серверов Google Карт. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<!-- позволяет API-интерфейсу проверять состояние подключения для определения возможности загрузки данных. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Настройки этого приложения:

[image]

**Откуда берутся разрешения на память и телефон, если я в манифесте их не прописал?**

Как вообще можно узнать, где они могут использоваться?
Использовал новый диалог на разрешение локации для андроид >=6.

Почему я вообще этим заинтересовался - когда грузил в маркет на публикацию приложение, вышел такой диалог

> Для разрешений, которые применяются в вашем файле APK (например,
>   android.permission.READ_CONTACTS), необходимо настроить политику
>   конфиденциальности.

Про политику я понял, но не понял зачем мне это показывают.

Собственно 2й вопрос - **этот диалог и мои разрешения в этом случае как-то связаны?**

Может ли быть, что у подключенных в проекте, библиотек есть свой список разрешений?

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.6.0'
compile 'com.github.paolorotolo:appintro:3.3.0'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

Comment: "Откуда берутся разрешения на память и телефон, если я в манифесте прописал?" - вы в манифесте прописали.

Comment: xD сейчас исправлю

Comment: @0xFFh, исправил

Comment: Посмотри, что у тебя в итоговом манифесте (ведь они мержатся из всех используемых aar). Расположен он где-то тут:
```./app/build/intermediates/manifests/full/debug/AndroidManifest.xml```

Comment: Какие именно пермишаны приходят из либы, можно посмотреть в их AndroidManifest.xml. Располагаются они где-то тут: ```app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/support-fragment/24.2.1/AndroidManifest.xml ```

Comment: @FeelGood, офигеть.. Вы правы, там добавочные разрешения выставлены. Подскажите пожалуйста, с этим итоговым манифестом можно делать какие-либо манипуляции? Или он такой же недотрога, как R.java ?

Comment: Надо понять кто просит, что не надо и может ли приложение вообще работать без этого пермишана. Его можно удалить. См. тут http://stackoverflow.com/a/31386964/310760

Comment: @FeelGood, выложите Ваши комменты, как ответ, пожалуйста

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Посмотри, что у тебя в итоговом манифесте (ведь они мержатся из всех используемых aar). Расположен он где-то тут:

`./app/build/intermediates/manifests/full/debug/AndroidManife‌​st.xml`

Какие именно пермишаны приходят из либы, можно посмотреть в их `AndroidManifest.xml`ях. Располагаются они где-то тут:

`app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/sup‌​port-fragment/24.2.1‌​/AndroidManifest.xml`

Надо понять кто просит, что не надо и может ли приложение вообще работать без этого пермишана. "Ненужный" пермишан можно удалить. См. тут https://stackoverflow.com/a/31386964/310760

Comment: От себя добавлю, подозреваю строку `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.6.0'`, так как там много неиспользуемого, а мне необходима только библиотека `com.google.android.gms.maps` для карт и местоположения. Сейчас буду конкретизировать в `build.gradle`

Comment: [https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup] ссылка для выборки нужных библиотек вместо `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.6.0'`, (её можно добавить в ответ, вдруг кто-то не поймёт решения)

Comment: всё, я заменил ту либу и у меня только одно разрешение, большое спасибо!